# How can videos be uploaded to a Bunny Net Server from Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming, bunnycdn

Explain the process of uploading videos to a Bunny Net Server from a Flutter application. Detail the necessary steps, including integrating Flutter with Bunny Net APIs, handling video file selection, and implementing the upload functionality. Emphasize the seamless interaction between Flutter and Bunny Net for efficient video hosting and sharing.

Despite my efforts, I have encountered challenges attempting to upload videos from a Flutter application to a Bunny Net Server. Unfortunately, I haven't located appropriate documentation to guide me through the process. I am seeking assistance or resources to overcome this hurdle and successfully implement the desired functionality.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "Despite my efforts, I have encountered challenges attempting to upload videos from a Flutter application to a Bunny Net Server." - what were the challenges, what effort you went through, also providing related [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could help.